# How to find by filed and add amount to another field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have PlayerModel which looks like ( using mongoose/mongo )

```
var PlayerModel = new Schema({
    playerUUID : String,
    score : Number
});
```

and I want to add `20` points to score with `playerUUID "1261236237621"`.
How to find and update PlayerModel ? Is possible to update as in sql in one statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the `PlayerModel` with the `playerUUID` you want and then update it, like:

```
var PlayerModel = new Schema({
  playerUUID : String,
  score : Number
});

var Player = mongoose.model('Player', PlayerModel);

Player.findOne({ playerUUID: "1261236237621" }, function (err, player) {

  if (err) throw new Error(err);
  player.score += 20;
  player.save(function (err, playerResponse) {

    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    // playerResponse is your updated Player
    console.log(playerResponse);
  });
});
```